# Nagios returning OK with check_http and status 303

Tags: http, nagios

Probably an easy question but search is not helping.

```
# ../libexec/check_http -H google.co.uk
```

Provides:

```
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently - 592 bytes in 0.153 second response time|time=0.152933s;;;0.000000 size=592B;;;0
```

But

```
# ../libexec/check_http -H google.co.uk.thisisnotarealurl
```

Provides:

```
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.0 303 See Other - 212 bytes in 0.161 second response time|time=0.161133s;;;0.000000 size=212B;;;0
```

How can it be showing HTTP OK when the site doesn't exist?

Nagios is showing the site is OK whether it exists or not, is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status `303` means the site is present, just somewhere else. Same for `301` (with different semantics). Thats not a Failure so yeah thats normal.

The question is why you get `303` for `google.co.uk.thisisnotarealurl`. Maybe some setup in your network (DNS proxy that always delivers some result? See also the comment of [James_pic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1927339/james-pic)!)

What do you get if you hit that into a browser (from the same machine & setup of Nagios)

Comment: Some unscrupulous ISPs have their DNS servers set up to intercept requests for incorrect domain names, and redirect them to sponsored search pages.

Comment: OpenDNS is the problem - returning a redirect if its not found. Going to just stick this in SCOM on another box instead, seems it'll be easier. Thanks all.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer not an option unfortunately - we just went with SCOM instead